# Divide time period into partitions and calculate averages

Tags: oracle, olap

I have to divide elapsed time of a process into slots of equal sizes and calculate number of rows inserted during each time slot.

Here is DDL of the table

```
  ID                  number
  insert_date_time    date
```

Sample Data

```
    101          Aug 1 2015 4:43:00 PM
    931          Aug 1 2015 4:43:01 PM
```

The output I am looking for is as follows

```
 Time Slot          Rows Inserted
4:00 pm  - 5:00 pm       103
5:00 pm  - 6:00 pm       95
6:00 pm  - 7:00 pm       643
```

( I have left out date portion for brevity )

Similarly, I have to find out how much time each 100 rows took

```
    0 - 100 rows        4:00pm - 4:43pm
  101 - 200 rows        4:43pm - 5:58pm
```

I know Oracle OLAP functions can be used for this, but not sure how ?

Comment: Please show how the data is represented in the tables.

Comment: Record layout is very simple. Just two columns - ID (number) and insert_date_time (date)

Comment: A date is not an interval.  Please **edit** your question, not the comments, and show show EXACT sample data representation of your table.

Answer (score 1):

Hoping I understood your requirement.

First Req#:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(INSERT_TIME,'HH24'),COUNT(*) FROM TABLE
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(INSERT_TIME,'HH24');
```

Second Req#:

```
SELECT ROUND((ROW_NUMBER-1)/100,0),
MIN(INSERT_TIME)      +'-'+ MAX(INSERT_TIME)
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY ROUND((ROW_NUMBER-1)/100,0);
```

Comment: I prefer the way you grouped the records in the 2nd query better than the way I did it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for 1 hour partitions, you can simply truncate the date column you are looking at to the hour `trunc(your_date_col, 'hour')` using that truncated value in your grouping clause.

For the 2nd requirement you can partition your rows with a query like this:

```
with data as (
select a.your_date_col
     , row_number() over (order by Your_Date_Col) rn
     , row_number() over (order by Your_Date_Col) -
       mod(row_number() over (order by Your_Date_Col)-1,50) grp
  from your_table a
)
select min(rn) ||' - '
     ||max(rn) ||' rows' rows
     , min(your_date_col)||' - '
     ||max(your_date_col) time_range
  from data
 group by grp
```